# Treat a number as an array

Tags: j

As far as I know, it is impossible to perform array operations on numbers in J; e.g.

```
NB. In J, this won't work:
m =: 234
    +/ m
9 
    */ m
24
```

Since I can't do it directly, is there a way to split a number into a list and back again, like this?:

```
    splitFunction 234
2 3 4
    +/ (splitFunction 234)
9
    |. (splitFunction 234)
4 3 2
    concatenateFunction (4 3 2)
432
```

If it is not possible, is there a way to turn a number into a string, and back again? (since J treats strings as character arrays) e.g.

```
     |. (toString 234)
432
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, there is a little bit to unpack here in what your expectations would be. Let's start with

```
   m=:234  NB. m is the integer 234

   +/ m    NB. +/ sums across the items - only item is 234
234
   */ m    NB. */ product across the items - only item is 234
234
```

so there seems to be confusion between the digits of the integer 234, which would be 2 3 4 and the fact that 234 is an atom that has only one item which has a value of 234.

Moving on from that, you can deconstruct your integer using `10 & #. ^: _1`  which consists of the inverse (`^:_1`) of Base (`#.`) with a left argument of `10` which allows the break up to be done in base `10`.  J's way of inverting a primitive is to use the Power conjunction (`^:`) raised to the negative 1 (`_1`)

```
   splitFunction =: 10 & #.^:_1
   concatenateFunction =: 10 & #.
   splitFunction 234
2 3 4
   +/ splitFunction 234
9
   */ splitFunction 234
24
   |. splitFunction 234
4 3 2
   concatenateFunction 2 3 4
234
       concatenateFunction splitFunction 234
    234
```

I think that this will do what you want, but you may want to spend a bit more time thinking about what you would have expected `+/ 234` to do and whether this would be useful behaviour.

Comment: You are right. I phrased my question poorly. Your answer is exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: Nice answer. Would just add that, given `concatenateFunction` is the inverse/obverse of `splitFunction`, there is the opportunity to use `under` or `&.` to simplify things. That is  `|.&.splitFunction 234` . Roughly translated to English this says, "Apply the verb splitFunction to the argument before reversing (`|.`) the result and then applying the obverse of splitFunction to that result.". For many verbs J can work out what the obverse is. See https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/ampdot for more information.

Comment: NB. One reason to use inverse Base `#.^:_1` instead of the more obvious Antibase `#:` is that `10&#: 234` yields just `4`. While `10 10 10 &#: 234` gives the right answer `2 3 4`, the code required to get the right number of 10s on the left side is probably not worth it.